# Tensor products between $C^m(K)$ and Banach space $X$

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products

the following is an excerpt from Section 3.2 in from Ryan's *Introduction to Tensor Products of Banach Spaces*:

> We now investigate injective tensor products with the space $C(K)$ of
> continuous functions on a compact topological space $K$. We shall show
> that the injective tensor product $C(K) \hat{\otimes}_{\varepsilon} X$
> can be identified with the Banach space $C(K, X)$ of continuous
> functions from $K$ into $X$, where the norm on this space is given by
> $\|f\|_{\infty}=\sup \{\|f(t)\|: t \in K\}$.

The section continues explaining first why this holds true, and then discussing how the  injective tensor product respects quotients.

I would like to use a result of this type, but where $C(K)$ is replaced by $C^m(K)$, for some integer $m$. I do not think that this result is in Ryan's book, even though I can imagine how his arguments can be adapted to this case.

Do you know of any reference that I could cite where this result is proved?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the precise result you want to achieve? From this description it should be clear that we have an continuous embedding $C^m(K)\otimes _{\epsilon}X\to C(M,K)$. But I am not sure how to make sense of $C^m(K,X)$, do we take Frechet derivatives and $K$ a compact manifold?

Comment: My interpretation of Ryan's result is that there is an isometric isomorphism between $C(K) \hat \otimes_\varepsilon X$ and $C(K,X)$. I would like that there be an isometric isomorphism between $C^m(K) \hat \otimes_\varepsilon X$ and $C^m(K,X)$. The space $C^m(K,X)$ is defined as the set of mappings on $K$ to $X$ for which Frechet derivatives of order up to $m$ exist and are continuous. A possible norm is $\| u \| = \sup_{t \in K} \sum_{j=0}^k \| D^k u(t) \|_X$